Salesforce create-job-bulk-api-v2 Upsert operation for UpdateOnly
I'm using Salesforce create-job-bulk-api-v2 with Upsert operation in Mule 4 and as per this documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.250.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_upsert_patch.htm
We can prevent new records to be created and use this to update only. How can I set updateOnly to True? I tried using this
<salesforce:create-job-bulk-api-v2 objectType="Account" operation="upsert" doc:name="Create job bulk api v 2" doc:id="c43d3dc1-0f9f-416e-9c2d-9330a9861cb4" config-ref="Salesforce_Config" externalIdFieldName="External_Id_c">
                <salesforce:headers >
                    <salesforce:header key="updateOnly" value="true" />
                </salesforce:headers>
    </salesforce:create-job-bulk-api-v2>

but still new contact is being created.

You should explain why using upsert is a requirement but you don't want to create new records.

@aled I don't want to add an extra GET call.

Isn't update an option for the operation? Currently you have set it to upsert

As per my research bulk api v2 doesn't allow updateOnly parameter.
